# don't work redirect with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-16.04

I work local on my machine. I have some problems with redirect through .htaccess. In my web-application I have 2 redirect through 2 .htaccess files.

I have next structure my app:

root:

- application (dir)
- public (dir)

  - index.php
  - .htaccess
- .htaccess

In first .htaccess file has next code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$ [L]
</IfModule>
```

but it doesn't work. In browser I see next picture [view in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syX84.png)

I change file apach2.conf and add

```
<Directory /var/www/my-site/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

but it don't help fix problem.
What I must do to it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```